# Which frameworks for C# desktop applications work on Windows XP or later?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop-application, desktop

I'm going to develop a software for managing gyms with C# on Visual Studio that needs to run on any version of Windows without installing any framework updates or anything else.

Is that possible?

I heard somewhere that .NET Framework 2.0 is included in all currently supported versions of Windows.

Comment: Not if you want to support XP - see http://www.msigeek.com/2390/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-which-version-of-the-os for the full list

Comment: `any version of windows` is far to broad.  Please try to narrow it down some.  Are you referring to the currently support versions (Windows XP and later)?  What about Server versions of Windows?

Comment: Try setting .NET framework version to 4.0 this is latest version I was able to run on winXP when created application on newer windows OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! A good question to answer first is: What versions of Windows do you want your application to work with? "Any" is pretty big. The oldest version of Windows that .NET runs on is Windows 98, but the oldest version of Windows that comes with .NET already installed is Windows Vista.

If you target .NET 2.0 or 3.0, you'll be compatible with the widest variety of Windows versions which come with .NET as part of the OS.

Comment: Thank you!

The software i am going to develop doesn't need much resources, i am going to use MySQL for the database, i think framework 2.0 will do the job.

Comment: Good deal. On computers running a version older than Vista, .NET might have been installed through Windows Update or other means; it just isn't guaranteed, is all.